# How do you leave comments in Azure Synapse Analytics views and what are the best practices for comments?

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, azure-synapse

I'm seeking out best methods for adding coding comments to views in Azure Synapse Analytics. Synapse has been a bit tricky to use since some of what I expect to be basic T-SQL are not available in Synapse.

When creating views, I'd like to create a leading changelog and comment block. I'm not sure if there is a best method for doing so. Some cursory research provides different solutions, namely putting a comment before the `CREATE` statement or between the `AS` and `SELECT` statement. Neither of these methods work in Synapse Analytics.

My interim solution has been to add leading and trailing parentheses:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Some_View
AS
(
/***
Purpose:    Returns a list of content with creator names after 1/1/2023.
Changes:    2023-09-05 OrphanedRecordAnnie Added additional field Creator_Name.
***/
SELECT Creator_ID
     , Creator_Name --added 2023-09-05
     , Created_Content
FROM dbo.Creations
WHERE Created_Date >= '2023-01-01'
)
;
```

This method works but seems like another workaround.

Tried statement before `CREATE` and after `AS`:

```
/** leading statement - not retained **/
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Some_View
AS
/** after AS - not retained **/
SELECT Creator_ID
     , Creator_Name --added 2023-09-05
     , Created_Content
FROM dbo.Creations
WHERE Created_Date >= '2023-01-01'
;
```

Based these tries on this question [How do you leave comments in SQL Server 2008 R2 view with SSMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381626/how-do-you-leave-comments-in-sql-server-2008-r2-view-with-ssms) and looking at simple best practices articles like this one: https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/sql/comments-in-sql/.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you've covered almost all the bases already - it seems the common methods just aren't supported in Synapse.  The only one left that you haven't mentioned (that I can see) is putting the comment after the first word of the view.  i.e. SELECT   /* comment */  <list of columns>.

Comment: @Celador Thank you for the response! I don't prefer that method since it breaks up reading the code (IMO), but good for awareness.